# Symfony2 three roles

Tags: symfony

I'm working on a project using symfony.
I specified three roles : ROLE_USER, ROLE_ENTERPRISE, ROLE_ADMIN. what I would like to do is to create separate roles.

1. I don't want to let the ROLE_ENTERPRISE be inherited from ROLE_USER
   and vise versa.
2. I don't want to let the ROLE_ADMIN be inherited from ROLE_USER and
   vise versa.
3. I don't want to let the ROLE_ENTERPRISE  be inherited from
   ROLE_ADMIN and vise versa.

I tried to do it but it's not working . here is my `securty.yml` file

```
role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ENTERPRISE:    ROLE_ENTERPRISE
        ROLE_USER:  ROLE_USR
        ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: simply don't use `role_hierarchy` if you don't need to create a role hierarchy.

Comment: I have to remove all the script ?

Comment: You can remove the `role_hierarchy` section entirely from `security.yml` or leave it blank.

Comment: thanks it's working :)